# Installing impala from source to an actual cluster

Tags: cloudera, impala

Is there any documentation for installing impala from source (I have a customized codebase of impala) to a real cluster instead of the minicluster scripts included with the source code?

Given that the cluster already has CDH with HBase installed on it with cloudera manager.